# Django: object has no attribute 'was_published_recently' - except it does

Tags: python, django

Similar but not the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424854/django-object-has-no-attribute-was-published-recently).

New to Django, I've been doing the 1st tutorial and I'm at part 5 now, which is automated testing.

After following the tutorial until step "Fixing the Bug", it pops up an error when I run the test, as follows:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_was_published_recently_with_future_question (polls.tests.QuestionModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ian/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 18, in test_was_published_recently_with_future_question
    self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Here's my code:

**tests.py**

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Question


class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is in the future.
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Try deleting your .pyc files and re-running the tests

Comment: ^^ nothing changed Borko Kovacev

Comment: you should check the `Question` model from the shell, or from the admin site, and make sure you can call the method  (jump [some steps in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-change-list))

Answer (score 2):

You have to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> (stop) your python console, then run python `manage.py` shell again and finally import all again. It will work now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this way  this is helpfull for me

polls/models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
# Create your models here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
```

To

```
future_question = Question.objects.get(pub_date=time)
```

Comment: 1. filter return queryset -- `future_question.was_published_recently()` will have error, and in queston is need new instance of `Question`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, however I then receive the following error:    

    ERROR: test_was_published_recently_with_future_question (polls.tests.QuestionModelTests)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ian/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 18, in test_was_published_recently_with_future_question
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
    AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'

Comment: Sorry I did .filter instead of .get. I just update my answer with it. Please try that way

Comment: Thanks again csling, the new error follows:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ian/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 17, in test_was_published_recently_with_future_question
    future_question = Question.objects.get(pub_date=time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: Question matching query does not exist.

Comment: I am not sure what timedelta is doing to try time.now() when you add it, but when you have that database query with .get, it's looking for anything in the database where pub_time=time. That means whatever your time variable is, it needs to match the pub_date field exactly in the database. That's why you're getting that most recent error. It's not matching anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Django is doing some magic in the Model class(most likely), the Question object creation with the the pub_date attribute is undefined as far as python is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
**exit()**. Exit out of the python shell.
Then reinvoke the Python shell.
Import the model classes.
The method should work.